# I am creating new sample project in linux using cmd sudo expo init my-app. getting git permission error

Tags: react-native, expo, git-clone

While making new project. Getting error,

```
silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-native-maps@github:expo/react-native-maps#v0.22.1-exp.0 
Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b v0.22.1-exp.0 git://github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git /home/avtar/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f6a69039764 
silly fetchPackageMetaData /home/avtar/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f6a69039/.git: Permission denied
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I was running into other problems using Expo on Windows 10, so I pulled out a MacBook Pro, did a fresh install of Mojave, and installed everything. Then I tried to `expo init` a project and immediately ran into this error.

Comment: Having the same problem on my mac. Any solutions to this? @DavidCanora

Comment: @SoftwareTheory  I installed git and rebooted.

Comment: Hi @DavidCanora thanks for getting back. The thing is git was already installed on my machine. Here is how I solved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604946/how-to-solve-the-git-permission-denied-problem-with-expo-init-on-macos

Comment: @SoftwareTheory Glad you found a solution. It's interesting - I ran into a problem with node because I used sudo to install packages. Had to reinstall node (and IIRC git too)  without sudo to get everything working correctly again. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem and fixed it by installing git and rebooting.